# How to make Unity Parent Game Object ignore child Sprite whose dimensions are bigger?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game object to place sword sprites in it for the parent object. To accomplish this, I've made sword sprites which are bigger than the parent sprite (parent is 256x256, sword is 384x384), so that the weapon size is not limited by the size of the parent sprite:

[image]

[image]

I've made it so all of these images' pivots are at the center, so in theory when the sword attack animation plays the sword game object should show the sprites from the center of the parent. While that does appear to happen, it seems the inclusion of these bigger images affect the parent game object dimension:

[image]

So, aside from addressing possible delays and z-index, it seems that because the image is bigger, the parent game object gets pushed down to ensure the top of the bigger image (the sword in this case) is stuck to the parent's top. Is there a way then to ensure child image dimensions are ignored so that the parent image doesn't displace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that, because I had all sprites' pivots as `Bottom Center` and I had changed the sprites specific to this animation to `Center` (so the sword and the hero would align) that the position of the sprites would change with respect to the rest, producing the abrupt down shift. The lack of synchronization was also not due to (at least not strictly because of) lack of optimization, but rather because the sword animation's duration was 15 milliseconds while the body and all its other child sprites' animations for the attack were 18 milliseconds, so the system may have tried to compensate somewhere. Changing the sword animation to last 18 milliseconds (by adding 3 more at the end without a sprite) synced them.